# Set Google account without using newChooseAccountIntent()

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, accountmanager, google-account

i want to set google account for **GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2** but don't want to use it's newChooseAccountIntent method to set account.

Code :-

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = {DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA, DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY};

mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

 startActivityForResult(
                    mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                    REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);

 protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

          switch (requestCode) {

            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                        data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName =
                            data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
}
```

In the abovr code i don't want to use **mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent()** i just want to setAccount without this method, So it can possible.?

I seen this in Es File Explorer in google section to login google drive without using this method.

Comment: You can use GoogleSignInOptions and GoogleApiClient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you don't want to use newChooseAccountIntent()

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestIdToken(serverClientId)
                    .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_AUTHORIZE_CONTACTS);
```

Reference link: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: What is serverClientId .?

Comment: Visit reference link and check this section: 
"Get your backend server's OAuth 2.0 client ID"

Comment: you need to register your project in google developer console.

Comment: It's still ask for Choose account. I just want to direct choose account using webview and init GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2 

Refer :- Es File Explorer in google section to login google drive